# Attempting to pass the nth specified element after splitting a String array

Tags: java, xml

Good afternoon coders.

For the below I have this same XML Snippet

```
<E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
    <QUALF>001</QUALF> 
    <IDTNR>101-CB-PI</IDTNR> 
</E1EDP19>
<E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
    <QUALF>002</QUALF> 
    <IDTNR>101-CB-PI</IDTNR> 
    <KTEXT>OXY MED 0,47KG PI/J44.9/0201/97062</KTEXT> 
</E1EDP19>
<E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
    <QUALF>003</QUALF> 
    <IDTNR>6005919004334</IDTNR> 
</E1EDP19>
<E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
    <QUALF>006</QUALF> 
    <IDTNR>MEDLRG</IDTNR> 
</E1EDP19>
```

For every instance of QUALF being 002 I need to take KTEXT and split it by the /

I did this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < QUALF.length; ++i){ 
        if (QUALF[i].equals("002")){
            text = KTEXT[i];
         String segments[] = text.split("/");
         finalResult = segments[1];
         result.addValue(finalResult);
        }
}
```

However I would like access the 2nd element (segments[1]) in the first use of this code, ie. J44.9

In the 2nd use of this code I would need to access the 3rd element, ie. 0201

I get an arrayoutofbounds[1] exception currently. unless i alter the sample by making the

```
<E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
    <QUALF>002</QUALF> 
    <IDTNR>101-CB-PI</IDTNR> 
    <KTEXT>OXY MED 0,47KG PI/J44.9/0201/97062</KTEXT> 
</E1EDP19>
```

The 1st Instance.

Comment: which array is out of bounds? I assume it is `KTEXT`. I guess your `QUALF` array has more items in it. If there is no KTEXT element in the subtree you need to add an empty string to your KTEXT array, so both arrays contain the same amount.

Answer (score 0):

You are using i for both the index into QUALF and KTEXT. This means that if QUALF[i]==002 is the 5th element, i will be 4 and you are out of bounds in KTEXT.

If I understand you right, you want to make a second index (j) that is initiated as 1, and increment j by 1 each time you are inside the IF.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < QUALF.length; i++){ 
            if (QUALF[i].equals("002")){
                text = KTEXT[i];
                String[] parts = text.split("/");
                for (int j = 0; j < parts.length; j++){ 
                    if (j == 1){
                        String nthWord = parts[j];
                        result.addValue(nthWord);
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Thanks people. As pointed out a 2nd loop within the initial to cater for the 2nd field argument.

This is then used to identify the 2nd element in the array by [j].

Cheers.